# How to render a component in React without putting it in a render() method?

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

I am using Ant Design (antd) in my app, and it has a component called [Modal](https://ant.design/components/modal/). This Modal is rendered following the standard flow of React, that is, declaring a `<Modal/>` component on your `render()` method.

And if you check the Modal docs, you can see that there is a [Modal.method()](https://ant.design/components/modal/#Modal.method()) that also renders a component, but without having to declare this component on `render()`, as it is done with the standard `<Modal/>` component.

My question is: how can I implement my own customized `Modal.method()` component (e.g. `Modal.login()`) that has its own logic, its own state, its own render etc, that just returns a value in a callback function when the user finishes using the component by clicking Ok, or performing any other action? This component would be used just like this `Modal.method()`, that is, blocks the usage of the other components until it finishes its flow and a value is returned.

Here is an [working example](https://codepen.io/arinze/pen/wxYjdL?editors=1111) of `Modal.confirm()` on codepen.io. I want to understand the logic of how can a component be rendered if it is not a `<Component/>` declared in any place of any `render()` method.

Comment: If that's an external library, you can check to view something, it's always written in the render method. Check for that library in node modules

Answer (score 0):

So I believe you're actually asking a couple questions wrapped into one.

One of the questions it appears you are asking is about the [renderProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) pattern.

This is how antd (and many react libraries in general) function in a "react" way e.g (this is antd's footer component):

```
<Modal
          visible={visible}
          title="Title"
          onOk={this.handleOk}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
          ***footer={[
            <Button key="back" onClick={this.handleCancel}>
              Return
            </Button>,
            <Button key="submit" type="primary" loading={loading} onClick={this.handleOk}>
              Submit
            </Button>,
          ]}***
        >
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
        </Modal>
```

I added some emphasis around the renderProps part of this component.

Render props allow you to write and think a more react-friendly way by storing everything into components.

e.g for your custom content you could write some modal content as a general container for your modals, then pass in data (e.g fed from redux/an api) and pass that down and it could appear as:

```
<Modal

modalContent={ 
<div>
{content from redux/wherever}
</div>}

</Modal>
```

As a general rule though, you must return everything within a render (either in a class or a functional component).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using ReactDOM.render, like we bootstrap the application.

A simple example

```
function ModalComponent() {
  return (
    <div className="modal-class">
      <div>content</div>
    </div>
  );
}

function showModal() {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(div);

  ReactDOM.render(<ModalComponent />, div);
}

// now somewhere in app call

showModal();
```